# how to get the comment written with `Imagick::commentImage()`

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

In imagick we can write a comment like

```
$imagick->commentImage('This is my comment');
```

How to see this comment later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

`echo $imagick->getImageProperty("comment");`